# How to mix lists in python and see it in real time

Tags: python, list

I tried to do something like below:

```
a_list = [
    range(1, 4),
    range(5, 8),
    range(11, 14),
]
```

I wanted a result like that:

```
res = ['1 5 11', '1 5 12', '1 5 13', '1 6 11', '1 6 12', '1 6 13', '1 7 11', '1 7 12', '1 7 13',
       '2 5 11', '2 5 12', '2 5 13', '2 6 11', '2 6 12', '2 6 13', '2 7 11', '2 7 12', '2 7 13',
       '3 5 11', '3 5 12', '3 5 13', '3 6 11', '3 6 12', '3 6 13', '3 7 11', '3 7 12', '3 7 13',
      ]
```

How can I get it

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Share it no matter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: Why did you just change the purpose of your post ? Also no-one will be notified of this so you don't have more or modified answers^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining `itertools.product` and `' '.join` you can do it

```
from itertools import product
# product(*a_list) [('1', '5', '11'), ('1', '5', '12'), ('1', '5', '13'), ...
prod = map(' '.join, product(*a_list)) # ['1 5 11', '1 5 12', '1 5 13', '1 6 11', ...
print(list(prod))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the Cartesian product of the sublists.

```py
from itertools import product

a_list = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['5', '6', '7'],
    ['11', '12', '13'],
]

list(product(*a_list))
```

That will give you a list of tuples. If you need a list of lists instead, try:

```py
[list(x) for x in product(*a_list)]
```

And finally if you want space separated strings:

```py
[' '.join(x) for x in product(*a_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
a_list = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['5', '6', '7'],
    ['11', '12', '13'],
]

b_list = [' '.join(i) for i in itertools.product(*a_list)]
print(b_list)
```

Result is:

```
['1 5 11', '1 5 12', '1 5 13', '1 6 11', '1 6 12', '1 6 13', '1 7 11', '1 7 12', '1 7 13', '2 5 11', '2 5 12', '2 5 13', '2 6 11', '2 6 12', '2 6 13', '2 7 11', '2 7 12', '2 7 13', '3 5 11', '3 5 12', '3 5 13', '3 6 11', '3 6 12', '3 6 13', '3 7 11', '3 7 12', '3 7 13']
```